Quarkus build unsatisfied dependency and runtime issues
So i'm working in a serverless environment. I was using weld-cdi before using quarkus-cdi and was thinking about migrating my CDI.
We are not really in a maven submodule architecture here.
So i'm using maven and :

I have a project A. I made a framework project.

I have a project B where i add the dependency of project A in it.


i will avoid all the issues i add to build with quarkus because i used some pom parent and some bom dependecy fully custom and it sometimes have weird behaviour.
So mainly i can build my project A. I have a beans.xml and i also added a jandex.idx with the plugin.
When i try to build my project b i have some problem with unsatisfied dependency.
Unsatisfied dependency for type DatabaseManager and qualifiers [@Default]
My DatabaseManager implement @Singleton annotation and i use @Inject in my project B to use it.
I can see that the project A jar in my .m2 has in his meta-inf the jandex file and the beans.xml
I've seen a lot of people having this kind of problem with multi module project but i'm not really in a multi module kinda setup, i have 2 seperate projects.
Also, i would like to know something, i'm using a JVM on my system. To start the program i call the main of the project A. In my classpath i have ProjectA.jar and ProjectB.jar. With weld, my project B beans were instantiate, but will quarkus do the same, i made some "unusual" tests but impossible see my beans instantiate maybe because i couldn't build properly my jar with the error above.
I'm expecting building my project B properly.
At runtime i expect to run my project A main and have all my beans instantiate by just having my jar in my classpath

I find it difficult to picture the structure you are using - from the description, your project B uses bean DatabaseManager and so the bean definition needs to either reside in B or you deep to have dependency on A to avoid unsatisfied dependency. Both projects should have beans.xml as a marker file for Quarkus to try and find beans within it. Other than that, I would suggest trying to reproduce this with a minimal greenfield project resembling your structure and going from there.
